# Calcular troco entre textbox?

Tags: c#

Boa noite , tenho 3 textbox, e gostaria que alguem disponibilizasse um codigo para me ajudar, quando seleciono o produto no grid o valor total é adicionado no textbox1, e assim por diante , quanto mais eu adicionar produtos , mais ele soma, pois bem ... gostaria de um codigo que ao digitar o valor recebido no textbox2 , ja aparecesse o troco no textbox3, nao sei se eu teria que usar um keypress ou algo do tipo, por isso preciso de ajuda.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não é so pegar o valor do textbox `Valor total` e diminuir do textbox do `valor recebido` e jogar no textbox `Troco`? Pode usar o evento `TextChanged` para realizar o calculo toda vez que o usuário alterar o valor, ou o evento `KeyDown`, tipo o usuário pressiona `enter` e realiza o calculo. ou pode fazer quando ele perde o foco do `textbox` realizar o calculo.

Comment: Sim, mas vc poderia me passar o codigo ? Sou novato em c# teria que ser mais claro para que eu entenda, se puder postar um codigo eu agraceria .

Comment: Gostei do evento keydown, como posso faze-lo ?

Comment: De uma lida neste [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh465336.aspx) na parte onde diz criando um manipulador de eventos.

Answer (score 1):

Um exemplo amigo, seria assim:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void textBox1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Enter key pressed");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Lembre-se, existe sempre a documentação oficial para ser consultada:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.onkeydown(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: Ok, este evento eu faço no textbox valor pago, mas eu nao preciso do codigo da subtração dos valores ? infelismente tbm nao sei , poderia me ajudar ?

Comment: Obrigado Danilo , consegui com seu código! abraço

Comment: Obrigado Meu Chapeu , me ajudou muito também! abraço